# ASP.NET Core parameter injection based on Route parameter

Tags: asp.net, .net, dependency-injection

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I would like a Route-parameter to determine the type of object that is injected into my controller.

Basically, the code should look like this:

```
public interface IConfig { String value{ get;set;} } 
public class ConfigA : IConfig { ... } 
public class ConfigB : IConfig { ... } 


    [Route("monitor/v{version:apiVersion}/blacklist")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BlackListController : ControllerBase
    {
    
      private IConfig _config;      

      public BlackListController (IOptions<IConfig> config) 
      {
         _config = config.Value;
      }
      // if route is /monitor/v1/blacklist then configshould be an instance of ConfigA 
      // if route is /monitor/v2/blacklist then config should be an instance of ConfigB
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it natively.
If you want to use different interface implementations depending from rout you must need to implement your own dependency resolver and add it to DI container.

Example code:

```
 public delegate IConfig Resolver(ConfigType key);
 services.AddSingleton<Resolver>(serviceProvider => key =>
        {
            return key switch
            {
                ConfigType.ConfigA => serviceProvider.GetService<ConfigA>(),
                ConfigType.ConfigB => serviceProvider.GetService<ConfigB>(),
                _ => serviceProvider.GetService<DefaultConfig>(), //default: in switch
            };
        });
```

Comment: i  don't understand how this address the  problem. the problem statement is:
(1) if route is /monitor/v1/blacklist then config should be an instance of ConfigA 
(2) if route is /monitor/v2/blacklist then config should be an instance of ConfigB

I believe you are on to something but you need to draw the connection. how each route map to their respective Types.

Comment: You can't change your injection parameters depending on dynamic events. This is static tree and it builds one time before application starts. If you want some dynamic behaviours you need to implement custom logic. You can't just put IOptions in construction parameters. You need to inject custom resolver, put it to constructor parameters, then call it inside your controller and get your configuration object.

Comment: Dmitriy Grebennikov, " inject custom resolver, put it to constructor parameters" . Please can you show an example for this, thanks.